# Electrostatic potential energy in the centre of two concentric shells

Tags: electrostatics

The centre has a potential that is equal to the potential of inner shell only. Why wouldn’t the outer shell contribute to the potential in the centre?

Take this image as reference.

[image]

Explanation using both graph and the formula or properties of electric potential would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "is equal to the potential of inner shell only".  If you mean the potential at a point a distance $a$ from the centre - then the potential at that point includes a contribution from the charge on the outer shell.

The main thing to realise is that the contribution of potential from one of the spheres doesn't change for different points within the sphere.

That is, the potential at infinity is zero, now we go towards the centre.   Let's say at radius $b$ the potential is 10V made up of 6V from the larger sphere and 4V from the smaller.  As we go inwards towards the smaller sphere, it's still 6V from the larger plus a rising contribution from the smaller sphere, say 6V+8V at $a$ giving 14V.  Then within the smaller sphere approaching the centre it stays at 14V.

The reason the contribution of potential from one of the spheres doesn't change within the sphere is that there is no electric field due to the sphere when inside it.

[image]